# How to speed up the comparison between two dicts with more than 100k items

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

The following code takes a while to execute.
I am trying to identify the values in c_imsi dict that are not in h_esmimsi dict, and vice versa.

c_imsi and h_esmimsi have more than 100,000 entries.

c_imsi = {1 : '36565', 2 : '34545',...,1011456 : '65342', ...}
h_emsimsi = {1 : '36545', 2 : '34545',...,1011456 : '36565', ...}

```
for k, v in c_imsi.iteritems():
        for k1, v1 in h_esmimsi.iteritems():
            if v == v1:
                matchfound = True
                write_csv.writerow([k1,v1,h_esmmsisdn[k1],'',k,v,c_msisdn[k],'OK'])
                break
        if matchfound == False:
            write_csv.writerow(['-','-','-','',k,v,c_msisdn[k],'NOK'])
        matchfound = False

    for k, v in h_esmimsi.iteritems():
        for k1, v1 in c_imsi.iteritems():
            if v == v1:
                matchfound = True
                break
        if matchfound == False:
            write_csv.writerow([k,v,h_esmmsisdn[k],'','-','-','-','NOK'])
        matchfound = False
```

Please how can I speed up this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how effective it is in memory, but it seems to be faster then TLOwaters method (by my testing with two 30k element lists about 2x), if it is only the goal to find out which elements are not in the other list.

```
output = {key: value for key,value in a.iteritems() if value not in b.viewvalues()}
```

Comment: Thanks C.Fe. No memory issues with your code and it is about 3x faster.
From 30 mins to about 10 mins. This is fair enough.

Comment: @Austin Aigbe Good to hear that, I am quite new to python so its awesome to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a list comprehension you should be able to speed up the process a bit. Just use the form:

```
output = [[k,v,k1,v1] for k, v in c_imsi.iteritems() for k1, v1 in h_esmimsi.iteritems() if v == v1]
```

And then loop through to write to the csv.

Alternatively write the dictionaries to a 'pandas' dataframe and do a left join on the values column in both directions.

Comment: It consumes a lot of memory:

    `python ldif_compare.py file1.ldif file2.ldif
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "ldif_compare.py", line 178, in <module>
     export_to_csv()
     File "ldif_compare.py", line 84, in export_to_csv
     o = [[k,v,k1,v1] if v == v1 else [k, v, "-", "-"] for k, v in c_imsi.iteritems() for k1, v1 in h_esmimsi.iteritems()]
     MemoryError`

Comment: I am looking for a solution that is both memory efficient and fast enough, at least less than a minute to run. My code is memory efficient but it take about 30 mins.

Comment: If you use the code I've changed it to it should be much less memory heavy (not really sure why but it took like 10gb of RAM for me too). I would highly recommend looking in to the pandas solution as merging using a table is both memory efficient and a lot faster in my experience. My original suggestion is the fastest possible way to do the comparison with lists. FYI doing it in 'at least less than a minute' isn't going to happen. You're doing 11-12 billion comparisons and writing to a csv file; it's going to take time. The amended method took 11 minutes for 2 sets of 100,000 dictionary items.

Comment: In case you are wondering what the pandas model might look like:
`df1 = p.DataFrame.from_dict(c_imsi, orient="index")
df2 = p.DataFrame.from_dict(h_esmimsi, orient="index")

all_df = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, how="left").set_index('index')

print(all_df)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the values into a dictionary the other way round?  The dictionary will take up a moderate amount of memory but will be very fast:

```
reversed_dict = {v:k for v,k in h_esmimsi.iteritems()}
for k, v in c_imsi.iteritems():
    try:
        k1 = reversed_dict[v]
    except KeyError:
        #  NOK
    else:
        #  OK

reversed_dict = {v:k for v,k in c_imsi.iteritems()}
for k, v in h_esmimsi.iteritems():
    try:
        k1 = reversed_dict[v]
    except KeyError:
        #  NOK
    else:
        #  OK
```